# Creating statistic Chart with Botframwork using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

the user should be able to evaluate the work of my chatbot at the end of Chatting with the bot. And the admins should be able to get the result of all the Evaluations in a Excel Sheet in my files, where my Node.js files are saved.
for example: 
User: Goodbye
Bot: were you satisfied with my performance? please click on the buttons so that I can improve myself! (the User should get two buttons, one for Yes and one for no).
if he choose one of them, i should get the statistic of all the histories of the Users Evaluation in my Statistic Chart of Excel.
How to do that? i need a code for that, please help me with this issue! thanks

Comment: You want the bot to display the chart or just be able to store the data so it can be put into Excel for the chart?

Comment: i want the history of the likes/dislikes for my Bot-Servies  like a chart in a Excel-fiel saved in my desktop files  and  monthly . I would be very thankful for every help!

Comment: It sounds like you've got a few different questions here. Could you break them down and get some code snippets of your attempts for each and consider posting them separately? (i.e. prompting user for input, saving a file to the bot, retrieving a file that's saved in the bot, etc) Consider looking at the [botbuilder node samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node) as well.

Comment: i saw the samples, could you tell me please, which of them is The most appropriate
with my case ? the user should get boolean Buttons (Yes, No), for the Question (were you satisfied with my performance? please click on the buttons so that I can improve myself!). And i (admin) should get the statistic chart in my desktop files like excel fiel.  How can i reach that please?

Comment: You'll probably want [prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) 
for the yes/no question, but as for the file save/load there's a lot more involved. Starting with setting up something in [table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet) is probably a good first step.

Comment: is that possible to modify a separate cell in excel-sheet without creating new fiel every time by Microsoft botframework? which Module should i use? i would be thankful for each help.

Comment: This module of npm helped me perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229089/creating-statistic-chart-with-botframwork-using-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this module of npm helped me perfectly: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node

Comment: Could you please add any details why did it help?